# How to show a custom validation message on a field in Lightning Record Edit form in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

HTML :

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <lightning-input-field field-name='Name'></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name='Phone'></lightning-input-field>
        <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
            <lightning-button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Create Account">
            </lightning-button>
       </div>
   </div>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

I want to throw a custom validation on name under the same name field and not as toast if name is duplicate. I tried writing a validation rule but it is coming as a toast message. I would like to have a red color highlighted field Name with custom validation message from JS side when name is duplicate. Is it possible? I would prefer if someone can help me with the code to throw any custom validation on a lightning-input-field.

Comment: Use `lightning-input` instead of `lightning-input-field` and then you can add custom validation to the lightning input.

Answer (score 0):

lightning-record-edit-form verifies data input based on your validation rules. The form submits and saves data input only if all data in the fields are valid. The form clears validation rule errors when an onchange event is fired on the overall form, and also when you update a field with a validation rule error.

If you want to add custom validation then you have to create your own custom form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shagun. I think you are right but from what i see if there is a custom validation rule on field level it is shown as a toast message when clicking on save button. Can we show this as a field level error in LWC.

Comment: I think you can use lightning-messages immediately before or after the lightning-input-field components to automatically display the string that's returned by message, and the detail or fieldErrors message if it's available. If you want detail information you can go through the documentation here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation 
I hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

The [`reportValidity()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation) method can be used to display the error messages on invalid fields. You can simply loop through all the input fields and check the `reportValidity()` of each field inside `onclick` event.

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account" onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
            <lightning-input-field field-name='Name'></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name='Phone'></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name='AccountSource'></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-button onclick={handleClick} variant="brand" type="submit" name="save"
                label="Create Account">
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class AccValidationDemo extends LightningElement {
    handleSuccess(event) {
        console.log('Account Id: ',event.detail.id);
    }    
    handleClick() {
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field').forEach(element => element.reportValidity());
    }    
}
```